# In Charlotte, when Yuu basically time leaps, does his brother keep his time leap power and does Yuu still have it?

Tags: charlotte

In *Charlotte*, when Yuu basically time leaps, does his brother keep his time leap power, and does Yuu still have it?

Very confusing, I don't think it was explained.

Answer (score 1):

If I have to take a guess Yuu's brother (Shunsuke) did kept his time leap power when Yuu himself time leaped.

The reason for this is because when you perform time leap. The consciousness is transferred to the past self instead of going back in time.

To prove the hypothesis let us take some facts into account and consider a scenario.

Facts :

1. When Shunsuke time leaped the history would repeat itself if different actions were not taken as to previous attempt.
2. When an action is taken the future becomes unpredictable, however it does not affect the ability of others

Scenario :
If Yuu didn't change the history when he time leaped the history would have repeated itself where his sister dies and he would eventually meet Shunsuke to take his time leap ability. This means that Shunsuke should have his time leap irrespective of Yuu time leap ability.

Yuu would also have his time leap ability as the user does not loose their ability and it was reference in anime when his eye was slashed.

The reason Shunsuke didn't time leap after Yuu got his time leap because to change the future the history need to repeat itself to the point where a mistake was made else the whole future would be unpredictable. Since Shunsuke didn't know the actions taken by Yuu if he had time leapt there was almost no chance to repeat the exact same history. As it creates a Paradox.

To explain the Paradox we need a timeline. I am considering a hypothetical points on timeline.

1. Lets consider the point A where Shunsuke usually time leap himself i.e. When Ayumi is 8 years old.
2. Lets consider the point B where Yuu take Shunsuke time leap ability
3. Lets consider point C when Yuu time leaps and save Ayumi.

If the history needs to repeat itself for the time leap user, there are now 2 possible futures for Shunsuke where Ayumi dies and where she lives at point C. This paradox was created because Yuu time leaped. If Shunsuke does time leap to point A and reach point C in time it can't be explained whether Yuu would have time leap or not.

I think that should be able to explain it. Anyways this is what I think, do let me know your opinions.