# In Charlotte (anime), Why do Yuu's older brother and his friends still have power in the current timeline?

Tags: charlotte

I'm very late to this fandom, but that doesn't stop me from finding out more about the strange things in this anime, I would also be very happy if we opened a discussion about Charlotte again xD

So, when they say these powers will disappear when they turn eighteen, then why do the people in the facility (Yuu's older brother and his friends) still have these powers? There is even a scene that shows this power can still be used normally

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [In Charlotte, when Yuu basically time leaps, does his brother keep his time leap power and does Yuu still have it?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/61425/2516)